# How to benchmark a daml ledger?

Tags: daml

I found this section "Benchmarking a DAML Ledger" on DAML documentation https://docs.daml.com/1.2.0-snapshot.20200602.4310.0.1c18058f/daml-integration-kit/index.html#integration-kit-benchmarking. However, i cannot find any example about how to evaluate the performance of the implementation. Could someone explain me about the ledger-api-bench tool please? Or any example please?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation refers to a tool that doesn't exist yet.

If you want, you can run performance test using the `--perf-tests-report` option (with a path where you want the textual report to be saved) and `--perf-tests` (with a comma-separated list of performance tests you want to run).

You can run the tests that you can find using the `--list` option. The tests available today (as of SDK 1.3.0) test latency, throughput and capability to process transactions of a given size for several levels of compliance (from the lowest `PoC` to the highest `Enterprise`).

Remember that in order to run performance test you must first load the test DAR, that you can obtain running the Ledger API test tool with `-x` or `--extract`.

Comment: thank you for your response! I extracted  Ledger API test tool i uploaded my dar file `daml ledger upload-dar mydarfile.dar --host localhost --port 6865` and finally `java -jar ledger-api-test-tool.jar --all-tests localhost:6865 --perf-tests-report /mypath`. On the terminal the test is succeeded but on my path there is no saved report. Do you know the reason?

Comment: `--all-tests` has been deprecated. Before that, it only ran conformance tests, not performance tests. Please check the documentation and use `--help`, those will tell you how to use those keys for the SDK version you are using. Use `--perf-tests` to run the performance tests. Use `--list` to see what performance tests are available. Due to a bug, misspelling performance test names can lead to run conformance tests instead of performance tests (I spotted this yesterday in order to reply and I'm currently working on it). https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/issues/6823